# Joomla component detail view error: 404 Could not load the item

Tags: joomla-4.x, custom-component, jtable

I have a table named `edu2f_jobs_jobs`.
This table is received here:

```
public function getTable($type = 'Job', $prefix = 'Administrator', $config = array())
{
    return parent::getTable($type, $prefix, $config);
}
```

Inside the JobModel there is a piece of code that does this:

```
// Get a level row instance.
        $table = $this->getTable();
        // Attempt to load the row.
        if ($table && $table->load($id))
        {


            // Check published state.
            if ($published = $this->getState('filter.published'))
            {
                if (isset($table->state) && $table->state != $published)
                {
                    throw new \Exception(Text::_('COM_JOBS_ITEM_NOT_LOADED'), 403);
                }
            }

            // Convert the Table to a clean CMSObject.
            $properties  = $table->getProperties(1);
            $this->_item = ArrayHelper::toObject($properties, CMSObject::class);

            
        }
        if (empty($this->_item))
        {
            throw new \Exception(Text::_('COM_JOBS_ITEM_NOT_LOADED'), 404);
        }
```

I get the error because `$this->_item` is empty.
However I don't know what is causing this or where to look.

Can someone help me with this or why this is happening?

Comment: As it hasn't been mentioned, have you created the Table/JobTable.php file?